# how to add the deprecated diagnostic plugin to a phonegap 4.2.0 app?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm very new to PhoneGap, and would like to include the GPS diagnostic tool in my app. The tool's docs seem to be obsolete, (the original plugin is [deprecated](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins), but there is a [branch here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/Android/Diagnostic)).

I have PhoneGap v4.2.0-0.26.0

I followed step 1 and 2, but I'm stuck with step 3, as I don't have a plugin.xml file to insert the following line
`<plugin name="Diagnostic" value="net.avantic.diagnosticPlugin.Diagnostic" />`
I do have a config.xml but inserting this line makes no difference, `window.plugins.diagnostic` is `undefined`

I also don't have the AndroidManifest.xml file from step 4.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying hard with that plugin too, but I couldn't make it work. So I tried another plugin, In my case I only need to check if GPS is enabled, The plugin is this: [GPSDetector](https://github.com/BastienL/GPSDetector). I used that plugin and it worked, I just added the java method switchToLocationSettings() from Diagnostic plugin for creating an Intent to let the user activate the GPS manually.

If you want to keep using Diagnostic plugin, maybe you can make it work as it says in GPSDetector's plugin:

> for Phonegap >= 3.0 :
>
> Add a feature line to res/xml/config.xml :

```
<feature name="GpsDetectionPlugin"> <param name="android-package" value="com.butterflyeffect.plugins.GPSDetectionPlugin" /> </feature>
```

Obviously changing the package name.